# How to avoid a Nested Query chain in a Custom Datasource complex result?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm developing a Custom DataSource to WSO2 DSS to use JPA entities and JPQL on data services.

What I've accomplished:

- I have a data source exposed as a JNDI and my persistence unit receive it by init params so I connect to it using JTA-DATA-SOURCE;
- All JPA native queries are working just fine with it (SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE .., UPDATE, DELETE);
- I've developed a custom JSON language for dynamic queries using REST (example: {_query : { field1 : { _like : "foo%" }, field2 : { _in : [1, 2, 3] }});
- Query decode and Java reflection are used to convert JPA result Objects and Objects[] into DataRows;
- BeanValidation is throwing DataServiceFault after execution;
- To secure entity references, reflection is used to refresh it all before commit.

**SCENARIO:** Different from SQL, JPA result aren't rows. It are entities and an JPA entity can be a very complex chain of objects.
At this moment **One to Many** JPA entities are treated manualy with Nested Query in DSS. This can difficult the developing process of a data service. 
I predict many cases where we'll have a Nested chain due to entity's relationship chains.

What I want to do without any modification in WSO2 core is to return this complex entity chain fetching it using EAGER type. Right now I think this is not possible because **DataRow** (interface) method "*getValueAt(String column)*" returns a String when in my case should return a String array.

Take a look at this DBS Sample query:

```xml
<query id="findAll" useConfig="default">
  <expression>SELECT c FROM City c</expression>
  <result element="cities" rowName="city">
     <element column="c.id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
     <element column="c.name" name="name" xsdType="string"/>
     <element column="c.code" name="code" xsdType="string"/>
     <element name="person"> 
        <element column="c.person.id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="c.person.name" name="name" xsdType="string"/>
     </element>
  </result>
</query>
```

With a little of reflection I converted the JPQL result object into a Map so **FixedDataRow** is working but when I have more than one person, the "c.person.id" key is overwritten. In this case Nested Query can solve the problem but I don't want to have two "" elements since JPA return a "3D" element different from SQL rows which return a "2D" object.

Take a look at this sample City object:

```js
{ 
   c.id : 1, 
   c.name : "Foo",
   c.code : 999,
   c.persons : [
      {
         c.person.id : 1,
         c.person.name : "Bar"
      },
      {
         c.person.id : 2,
         c.person.name : "Ano"
      }
   ]
}
```

See why "*getValueAt(String column)*" return should be *List<String>* or a *Map*?

The DBS for this should be something like that:

```xml
<query id="findAll" useConfig="default">
   <expression>SELECT c FROM City c</expression>
   <result element="cities" rowName="city">
      <element column="c.id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
      <element column="c.name" name="name" xsdType="string"/>
      <element column="c.code" name="code" requiredRoles="admin" xsdType="string"/>
      <element column="c.persons" name="persons"> <!-- List of Person -->
         <element name="person"> 
            <element column="c.person.id" name="id" xsdType="integer"/>
            <element column="c.person.name" name="name" xsdType="string"/>
         </element>
      </element>
   </result>
</query>
```

I found an element's attribute called "arrayName". Maybe it can help in the customization but I don't know how to use it:

```xml
<element arrayName="c.persons" name="persons">
```

**QUESTION:** How it can be developed without modifying WSO2 core source and avoid the mentioned Nested Query chain and simplify the data service developing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like explained in https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS310/Grouping+Data+into+Complex+Elements

FixedDataRow map expects a map of "columnName" "value" pair as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Yes @Rajith, is something like that, but it works fine when I have just one result in the complex element. When I have more than one, I should use Nested Query, because the FixedDataRow does not accept multivalued map and is that what I need, a complex element with multiple values without nested query, but I think is not possible.